# Doubt in Sum no 29 of Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that every open open set in $R$ is the union of a countable number of disjoint intervals.

Although this question has been in stack exchange for too many times but here is my intuition to it. Can someone just suggest whether I am on the right track.

I am taking the example of the open set $(a,b)$.So I take the first segment as $(a, b-1)$ , the second segment as $[b-1,b-1/2)$ the third as $[b-1/2,b-1/3)$ and so on...My logic behind this is that $(0,1-1/n)$ covers $(0,1)$ and so $(a, b-1/n)$ covers $(a, b) $.The intervals are disjoint also and their union  is also countable. Now, my question is the hint given in rudin is to use the fact that $R$ is separable , but where do I use it, Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Union of disjoint open intervals can be a single interval. In the case $(a,b)$ there is nothing to be done.

Comment: And every open set in R is in the form of (a, b)  so what exactly do I need to prove in this question?

Comment: That is not true. Not every open set is an open interval.

Comment: What are the sets which are not? - the finite sets?

Comment: $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ is open. There are many, many open sets which are not an interval.

Comment: @GuriaSona The finite non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are not open.

Answer (score 1):

> I am taking the example of the open set $(a,b)$.So I take the first segment as $\color{red}{(a, b-1)}$ , the second segment as $[b-1,b-1/2)$ the third as $[b-1/2,b-1/3)$ and so on...My logic behind this is that $(0,1-1/n)$ covers $(0,1)$ and so $(a, b-1/n)$
> $\color{red}{ covers}$ $(a, b) $.The intervals are disjoint also and their union  is also countable. Now, my question is the hint given in rudin is to use the fact that $R$ is separable , but where do I use it, Am I making a mistake somewhere?

From what you have written, I assume you mean

$$(a,b)=(a,b-1) \cup (b-1,b-\frac{1}{2}) \cup (b-\frac{1}{2},b-\frac{1}{3}) \cup \dots $$

But there are many issues with this logic. The mistakes are

$1$-What if $a > b-1$?

$2$-Your open set need not of the form $(a,b)$. It can be of the form $\bigcup_{i\in I}(a_i,b_i)$ where $I$ can be an **uncountable** set as well.

$3$-Secondly, Your LHS may miss the points $\Big\{b-1,b-\frac{1}{2},b-\frac{1}{3},\dots\Big\}$ , So you cannot say that your set $(a,b)$ is covered

Now the hint can give you an easier solution. You can think about that. The hint says that there exists a countable dense set. The set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$.